# Why my jupyterlab automatically restarted by itself (remote server)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using remote server with ssh and running jupyterlab there.
When I run some codeblock (It needs more than 5 min to run I guess), it automatically restart before I see the result.

Memory is enough. and log shows something strange

```
Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
Notebook .ipynb is not trusted
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```